# How to Add New Array Index in JSON using JsonPath?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'm trying to add one more index value to the path:

`$.data.library.category[2].book` using `jayway jsonpath` in following Json,

```
 "data":{
    "library":{
    "class":"CRED",
    "category":[{
                "book":"java 2.0"
            },
            {
                "book":"java 3.0"
            }]
    }
```

but i'm not getting updated response in result json.

My java code:

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);  
DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(sampleJson);
documentContext.set(JsonPath.compile("$.data.library.category[2].book"), "java 3.0");
```

I have checked also with `documentContext.add`. Nothing works out. Since the array has 0 and 1 index, i can update the value there by JsonPath. But it dont have 2nd index, so not updating. But I need to insert new index in the last of given json as per jsonpath.

Comment: I think the JsonParser use a LIST as backend for the JSON Array. So your have to use .get(index).

Answer (score 5):

Path `$.data.library.category[2].book` means that you want to update `3-rd` element in array. But there is no `3-rd` element yet. You need to create it first. You can add new element to array using `$.data.library.category` path. By providing a `Map` object you can define all required keys and values. See below example:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration()
                .addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL)
                .addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);
        DocumentContext document = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(jsonFile);

        JsonPath pathToArray = JsonPath.compile("$.data.library.category");

        document.add(pathToArray, Collections.singletonMap("book", "java 3.1"));
        document.add(pathToArray, Collections.singletonMap("book", "java 3.2"));

        System.out.println(document.jsonString());
    }
}
```

Above code prints below `JSON`:

```
{
   "data":{
      "library":{
         "class":"CRED",
         "category":[
            {
               "book":"java 2.0"
            },
            {
               "book":"java 3.0"
            },
            {
               "book":"java 3.1"
            },
            {
               "book":"java 3.2"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi , in this scenario it wont work for all cases right?

For Example:

you are hard coding path :

$.data.library.category

But, same scenario, if Library also an Array i need to Insert in following path:

$.data.library[2].category[2] 

how we achieve this?

Comment: @MageshMagi, you need to update a question and describe all corner cases you want to handle.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that `Json` class from https://github.com/karatelabs/karate can work for you.
Given

```
String json = {
  "data": {
    "library": {
      "class": "CRED",
      "category": [
        {
          "book": "java 2.0"
        },
        {
          "book": "java 3.0"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What you need to do is

```
Json.of(json).set("$.data.library.category[2].book", "java 3.1")
```

And your output will be

```
{
  "data": {
    "library": {
      "class": "CRED",
      "category": [
        {
          "book": "java 2.0"
        },
        {
          "book": "java 3.0"
        },
        {
          "book": "java 3.1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not worked for the scenario where `library` is also an Array, such as wanted to add `$.data.library[1].category[0].book`. I believe that this can be done, but maybe is not as simple as just using the set method